# Android activity chain causing cyclic behaviour

Tags: android

In my android app, I have two activities

mainactivity and erroractivity

main activity starts (on resume) it checks wifi-not connected it opens the error activity, which simply tells user wifi is off start it and then open the app

User now starts wifi - reopens my app, the last activity which was error activity now shows up again.
So in the onResume of error activity I check wifi state if connected I open the main activity using startActivity .

User is now on mainactivity but here comes the bug,

User now can no-longer press back button to end the main activity, because when he presses back, it seems to go to erroractivity which again opens the mainactivity,

Any ideas how to sort it out ?

Thanks,

Comment: Ha! Apparently when in doubt call `finish()`... though we could all be wrong. Post the LogCat errors so we can see what is really happening.

Comment: No, the answer is right, I am calling finish() and it solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which simply tells user wifi is off start it and then open the app

I assume that you send the user to the WiFi settings with an Intent and `startActivity()`. Try calling `finish()` after `startActivity()`.

Comment: thanks, for the extra info, Its better to redirect him to wifi settings

Answer (score 1):

On the `onResume()` of erroactivity, instead of launching mainactivity with `startActivity()` use `finish()`, to finish the erroractivity and go back to the the previous one on the stack (i.e. mainactivity).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not finishing the MainActivity you just need to call `finish()` in the error activity `onResume()` method if the wifi is connected...